# How to avoid overwriting data in a Generic sObject List?

Tags: apex

I am working with generic object types for first time, and not sure how to go about this. Please advice,how shall i go about creating mainObjectList by initializing the TempsObject within loop before adding to the List mainObjectList.

I have tried below ways :

1. SObject tempSObject = new SObject(); <-- throws an error Type cannot     be constructed: SObject
2. tempSObject = gd.get(sobjectName).newSObject();. .<----- this adds three empty objectType in the mainObjectList variable. Which    isn't    expected
3. mainObjectList.add(new List(tempSObject)); <--- Invalid initializer type SObject found for List: expected an    Integer    or a List of type SObject

   tempSObject = gd.get(sobjectName).newSObject();
   relatedTempSObject = gd.get(relatedSObjectName).newSObject();

   for(integer i=0;i < sobjectMapList.size() ;i++)
       {
           Map sObjLstMap = sobjectMapList[i];
           system.debug('sObjLstMap : ' + sObjLstMap);

   ```
       for(String field : sObjLstMap.keySet())
       {

           System.debug('--------field-----'+field);
           if(sObjLstMap.get(field)!=null && String.valueOf(sObjLstMap.get(field)).trim()!='')
           {
               if(fieldTypeMapping.get(field) == Schema.DisplayType.Date )
               {
                   if(field.contains('.'))
                   {
                       relatedTempSObject.put(field.split('\\.')[1],Date.parse('' + sObjLstMap.get(field)));
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       tempSObject.put(field,Date.parse('' + sObjLstMap.get(field)));
                   }
               }
           }
       }
        mainObjectList.add(tempSObject);  

   }
   ```

Am not sure, how in case of generic objects we can create mainObjectList without overwriting its data with TempsObject.

Comment: You can create a generic `List<Sobject>` just like any other list type. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @DavidReed  have already created List<sObject>, which is mainObjectList.    thats why am adding tempSObject to this List so i can get all the values of tempSobject within List<SObject>. But the values of TempsObject is all overrwritten in the final outcome of mainObjectList.

Comment: i know to solve this if i would have tempObject as a new instance and then added to List<Sobject> , this will solve my problem.   But as this is a generic sObjects, am not sure how to go about this using the TempSObject.Hope that clarifies my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue does not have to do with generic code *per se*. You are overwriting a single `sObject` instance each time you iterate through your `for` loop. The behavior would be exactly the same if it were an `Account` or `Contact` in this situation.

Adding an object to a `List` does not copy that object, so each time your `for` loop iterates, it overwrites the fields of `tempSObject` and then re-adds it to the list. As a result, at the end of your code, your `List` will contain `sobjectMapList.size()` count of *the same object*.

I do not fully understand what this code does, but it appears that you simply need to move the initializations of `tempSObject` and `relatedTempSObject` inside the loop. The behavior you observed of "adding three empty objects to the list" appears to be a completely different logic problem.

Comment: Agree, i need to initialize it, so i had already tried to instantialte   tempSobject and relatedTempSObject  within loop.... e.g by below ways
            1. tempSObject = new SObject();   <-- but this throws an error  Type cannot be constructed: SObject                               
           2 o tempSObject = gd.get(sobjectName).newSObject();.  .<----- this adds three empty object in the mainObjectList variable.                                       3. mainObjectList.add(new sObject(){tempsObject}) <---- this also it doesnt accept.

Comment: Hence am unable to figure out how to instantiate and add this as per point(3) in the above trials for Generic Object.

Comment: You may have other issues in your code. Options 1 and 3 are clearly invalid. Option 2 should have nothing to do with the count of records added to the list. Please edit your question - no debugging in comment threads.

Comment: right there was some more issues in my code...fixed and is working fine.